# Exercises from Emily Riehl's "Category Theory in Context"

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

So I am new to category theory and I am doing some exercises in [this book](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/context.pdf).

> Show that a morphism $f:x\rightarrow y$ is a split epimorphism
>   in a category $\mathcal{C}$ if and only if for all
>   $c\in\mathcal{C}$, post composition
>   $f_*:\mathcal C(c,x)\rightarrow\mathcal C(c,y)$ defines a surjective
>   function.

Here is my attempt:

"$\Rightarrow$":
Suppose $f$ is a split epimorphism and $s:y\rightarrow x$ is a
right inverse of $f$, that is $fs=1_y$ and let $g:c\rightarrow y$ be
a morphism.
Consider $t=sg:c\rightarrow x$.
Then
$$g=1_y g=(fs)g=f(sg)=ft$$
In other words, $t\in\mathcal C(c,x)$ is a morphism such that $ft=g$,
thus $f_*$ is surjective.

"$\Leftarrow$":
Consider $1_y$.
By surjectivity there exists $g:y\rightarrow x$ such that
$$1_y=(fg)1_y$$
This is true if and only if $g$ is a right inverse of $f$, thus $f$ is a split epimorphism.

I am unsure whether this is correct because the definition of epimorphism contains something like "if $hf=kf$ then $h=k$", but I did not use that here.
I know that I need a right inverse, but is this enough?

Comment: 1) first implication is fine. 2) second implication is not quite right; how do you conclude that $gf$ is the identity? 3) you do not need to worry that you did not use the epi property. The claim is that an arbitrary $f$ is a split epi iff $f_*$ is surjective. Think, in this case, of 'split epi' as one single term. You do not need to first show it is epi and then show it is split epi.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Thank you for your feedback, I have edited my answer. Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, it’s all good now.

Comment: As another comment, it's not hard to show that existence of a right inverse implies the epimorphism property. Thus it suffices to show the existence of a right inverse.